# Php if Else in form action

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

Im trying to make an online concert ticket system and this is my problem..

```
<?php 
    if($tickettype == 'VIP'){
        $action = "seats.php"; 
    }else if($tickettype == 'VVIP'){
        $action ="seats1.php";
    }
?>

<form action= "<?php $action; ?>" method="post">
```

And it doesn't work. Thank you in advance!

heres the full codes for the particular file that has a problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ariana Grande Concert</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="ariana2.jpg" height="300" width="260"></td>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>
            <h2>ARIANA GRANDE THE HONEYMOON TOUR</h2><br>
            <font face="Lucida Sans Unicode"> March 11, 2017<br>
            Grand Ballroom, Solaire Resort & Casino<br>
            Due to peoples demand, Ariana Grande is back in the Philippines<br>
            Ariana Grande Live in the Philippines on <b> March 11, 2017!</b></font>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<hr>
<br>
<center>

    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="gray">
        <tr>
            <td><font face=""><b>TICKET PRICES:</b></font></td>

            <td><b>VVIP:</b> <u>Php 25,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>VIP:</b> <u>Php 20,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>Upper Box A:</b> <u>Php 15,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>Upper Box B:</b> <u>Php 15,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>Lower Box A:</b> <u>Php 10,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>Lower Box B:</b> <u>Php 10,000.00</u></td>
            <td><b>General Ad:</b> <u>Php 5,000.00</u></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>

<br><br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2"><b>Ticket Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font>
<?php
    $TicketType = array('VIP' =>'VIP', 'VVIP' =>'VVIP', 'Upper Box A'=>'Upper Box A', 'Upper Box B'=>'Upper Box B', 'Lower Box A'=>'Lower Box A', 'Lower Box B'=>'Lower Box B', 'General Admission'=>'General Admission') ;

    echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">';
    foreach ($TicketType  as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';

if($TicketType == 'VIP'){
    $action = "index.php";
}else if ($TicketType == 'VVIP') {
    $action = "seats.php";
}

    echo '<font face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font>';

    $Quantity = range (1, 30);
    echo '<select name="Quantity">';
    foreach ($Quantity  as $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>\n";
    }
echo '</select>';



?>

<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
<br><br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Next</button>

<style>
    .btnExample {
    color: #0000;
    background: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #0000;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px;
    }
</style>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Heres the full codes of the webpage that has a problem.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what, specifically? Do you get an error? Did you forget to `echo` your variable?

Comment: there isn't enough code for the form and the missing closure for it. Plus where those variables are and assigned as.

Comment: `echo $action;` will solve your issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I take it you had a good filling lunch.

Comment: Are you running this from a webserver? How are you opening the file?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think they're only answering to answers; post one, maybe you'll get the attention that's required to solve this one. The `</form>` that's missing with any inputs is unknown, as per the way they're using that file. I have my own thoughts on this, but feel I won't get a response, as already asked in comments earlier.

Comment: I am running it on browser localhost/foldernme/filename somethinglike this

Comment: Honestly @EricaMayManangan you've not posted enough code here for us to be able to help you. There are too many unknowns and we're having to ask question after question to try to discern what is going on with your code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question to provide the details necessary to help us help you.

Comment: Hmm okay thank you for helping me.

Comment: your code have several problem, first your missing input type submit, change your button to `<input type="submit">` than only your code will submit some thing, type button which you are using will not work, second you are using pure php it seems, and your select tag, it seems they are out side of form, will not work, first do one thing change your button to `<input type='submit' value='Hot air'>` it will direct you to the right file, first problem solve, only if and only your this submission problem get solved, adjust your your `<select>` tag,

Comment: `<Their was no space that's why i am posting this second coment> Read the above comment` if you are confuse what to change you have to change this line `<button class="btnExample" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Next</button>` this line to this `<input type='submit' value='Hot air'/>` and than check weather you are going to the right file or not, than only you  can change the value for your submit button, and than arrange your `select` at the moment they are at wrong place.

Comment: @EricaMayManangan are you taking a class for this or learning on your own? If you're learning on your own I would suggest going through some PHP tutorials as those would teach you the basics. There are many problems with your markup and code logic for which it would take us a long time to correct here.

Comment: I dont have enough knowledge about php because our professor did not teach us some basic codes thats why im trying to figure it out on my own

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 i will try to Change that later. Thankyou guys for helping me

Comment: dont accept my solution as a answer as it not the answer, it just long dam comment

Comment: @EricaMayManangan consider approving the answer that helped you out, so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 4):

You did not echo the variable to show the output:

```
<?php 
if($tickettype == 'VIP'){
    $action = "seats.php"; 
}else if($tickettype == 'VVIP'){
    $action ="seats1.php";
}
?>
<form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
```

Notice the `<?php echo $action; ?>`

Comment: It says access forbidden

Comment: Is that message coming after form submission?

Comment: Yes sir thats the message after submitting

Comment: That is because the server does not have access to show up page seats.php or seats1.php try changing file permissions of those files to 777 and try again.

Comment: How can i change that?

Comment: What operating system is your server (or your machine on which you are running the code on) running? Windows/Mac/Linux ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: DO NOT SET THE PERMISSIONS TO 777. That's just dangerous advice.

Comment: Okay so your do not need to change the file permissions, please ensure that the files seats.php and seats1.php lie in the folder where the form page lies. and then check again.
If the error persists then try putting die("I am here"); on both the files at the beginning. If it works that means that your code is redirecting the user to a page which does not have access to that page.

Comment: Yes that was a dangerous advice but was simply to check whether she has appropriate permissions on the file.. Either case she does not need to do that as she is having a windows machine and the code might be redirecting her.

Comment: Where to put that?

Comment: @EricaMayManangan Are you running a web server on your system?

Comment: Yes sir im using xampp

Comment: Either put the files in the same folder where your form page lies or in the following code add the path of the seats.php or seats1.php like: `$action ="path/to/seats1.php";`

Comment: Are all of your PHP files in the htdocs folder of XAMPP @EricaMayManangan?

Comment: How do you open them in your web browser? Are you using 'localhost/name_of_file.php' @EricaMayManangan?

Comment: Yes but its inside the another folder  'localhost/foldername/name_of_file.php'

Comment: does the file seats1.php and seats.php also exist in the same folder ??

Comment: She already [confirmed that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769159/php-if-else-in-form-action?noredirect=1#comment72655177_42769218) @ShaktiPhartiyal

Comment: Is Apache running @EricaMayManangan?

Comment: Yes its running

Comment: @JayBlanchard ill try to post the other codes tom.. I hope u'll help me thank u

Comment: Once you update just write a comment and ping me with the '@'

Comment: I posted it @JayBlanchard

Comment: The form file looks ok. Can you upload the code of seats.php and seats1.php ??

Comment: The form file *does not* look OK @ShaktiPhartiyal. The HTML is not valid for one thing, the `select` is not in a form element, `font` tags are deprecated, it's a real mess. You cannot change the value of an action with a drop-down in PHP, she'd need JS for that. `$TicketType` is not equal to `$Ticket_Type`. The PHP needs to be in a separate script which gets called by the form submit.

Comment: I thought the question was about php if else not working instead of deprecation in html tags, looks like I read the question wrong. @JayBlanchard I cannot find any `$Ticket_Type` in her code, again, I thought that you can give a name to a variable in php and it was not necessary to use the same name is html.. Looks like i'm mistaken..

Comment: Sometimes you have to dig a little deeper. What variable might this produce `echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">';`? In many cases you cannot just look at what the poster seems to be asking about when, if you approach the question holistically, you'll see there are other problems preventing the user from succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This is not the answer, and you should not accept this as answer, I am posting it here instead of posting in the comment section, because it's to long.**

`Note - You can solve your problem by your self, but for other it is impossible, as your code is just not making any sense at the moment, but I am pretty sure it will if you are able to read and understood what I am trying to say here in the solution.`

**First thing first,**

**Access Denied problem –**

*Note - you don’t have to fix this problem it will get fix by it self, but you should know why you have this problem, so in the future if you get the problem, you will know what to correct.*

The reason it denying the access is this, that you are not allow to give special character for `form action`  so after adding the `echo` in the `form` you are going to have this problem, because as soon as you add the `echo` in our `form action` you unknowingly giving special character to the action, because you never set the value for your variable `$action` so value for variable `$action` is equal to `error message`. So after adding the `echo` you are displaying that error message.

before doing any thing run your file in the browser and check the source code, 
and see the value in the `form action`, it will be some thing like this

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: action in <b>C:\in here you are going to have file path\form.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
```

notice how many angle brackets colon you got in the here, you are not even allowed one angle brackets, so browser is thinking you are trying to do some thing malicious and that's why its blocking your access.

*If you don’t know how to check source code,  just type how to see source code and give your browser name (don’t ask me it just one click away)*

***so your code is basically generating error message and displaying it for the action after adding the `echo` and that's why browser is blocking the access***

so why it was not doing the same thing before adding the echo, because in `php`, if you don’t use `echo` you are not displaying any thing, so before adding the echo, your `action was empty`, just remove the `echo` from the form action and check the source code again, you will understand what I am trying to say.

***Again you don’t have to fix it, it will get fix by it self, remember this.***

**Now the solution start from here**

***First I have to be right about my assumption, that what you are trying to do,***

```
So these are my assumption, what you want to do,
```

1. People should be able to buy different different types of ticket, and they can choose the number of ticket from 1 to 30,
2. Than you want to run different file according to the TicketType, in one case you want to run seat.php and in one case you want to run index.php,
3. And to achieve your goal, you created a form, use the if statement to set your action value in the form, as I can see you are using variable `$action` in the form for action, and you set this value through your if statement.

*If I am wrong about any thing up until now, don’t read further it will be waste of time.*

basically to achieve your goal, you are using `form, array and some logic`,

in your case you seems to know array and logic, but you lack pre basic knowledge about the form, and that's why your code is not working.

To be honest. In my opinion you know nothing about the form. That's why it is impossible to give you solution(at least for me). But I am quite sure, if you read this fully you will be able to solve your problem by your self,

***so give a quick read to the points, and you will be surprised how easy it is to solve your problem for you, and you will also realized why it is impossible for other to solve it for you, at the moment.***

**Now Start from here**

***I am dividing the problem in Four part***

1. Some important Notes about the `form`.
2. `$Ticket_Type` is not equal `$TicketType` - an you can not even use $TiccketType here
3. `Select option` only passes the `value` from the `value` tag-- Two part solution
4. Your logic is at the wrong place,

**1. Some important point about the form.**

1. When you use `form`, you have to tell `php`, that you are submitting the form, and if you want to do it only with `php`, you have to use submit button for it(I already mention this in my comment other day),
2. second you need to know, what happened when you click on the `submit button` in the `form`, form will run the `action file` and also will pass the data from. opening form tag `<form>` to closing form tag `</form>` to that file
3. but any data which is out of these opening and closing `form` tag,  `form` will not pass that data, so point is it only passes the data which is inside the opening `form` and closing `form` tag.

*Look at the code below to understand it better, and please also run this code, so you can understand it better,*

***Few points about the code***

1. in the below code, we have two `input field` `location` and `name`, `location` input field is out of the `form` tag and `name` input field is inside the `form` tag.
2. and our `form action` is `seat.php`, and `name` for `form` file is `form.php` for this example.
3. as our `action` is `seat.php`, so if you click on the `submit button`, it will pass the data to `seat.php`, and will run that file.
4. in `seat php`, we are just using `echo` to display both value,

**see the code below for `form.php` and for `seat.php`,**

***form.php***

```
Location<input type="text" name="location"/><br><br>//out side of the form tag

<form action="seat.php" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
    Location <input type="text" name="location"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Hot Air">
</form>
```

***seat.php***

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $name.'<br>';

$location = $_POST['location'];

echo $location;
```

Now go and run `form.php` and type some thing in the location and name box, and click on the submit button, and if you do that, it will only display you the `value for name` but for `location value` it will display you the undefined index location error.

***And the reason is, because your form never passed that value for `location` to `seat.php1, because`location`is out of`form` opening and closing tag,***

***Now put this Location field inside the form tag***

now put that `location` inside the opening and closing form tag,

*after doing that our code should look like this*

```
<form action="seat.php" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
    Location <input type="text" name="location"/><br><br>//Now location is inside of the form
    <input type="submit" value="Hot Air">
</form>
```

Now again run your `form.php` type some thing for `name` and for `location` and click on submit button, this time it will display you both the value, as this time both values are inside the `form tag` so both value get passed.

*Note – If you can understand the difference between the first result and second result, you will be able to understand, why you need to have your `select` tag inside the opening and closing `form` tag, you can not have them out side of,*

2. `$Ticket_Type` is not equal to `$TicketType` – ***and you can not even use $TicketType in here as it is equal to array you want value from the select option***

For Second mistake, pay attention to this portion of your code

```
echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">';

    foreach ($TicketType  as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';


if($TicketType == 'VIP'){
    $action = "index.php";
}else if ($TicketType == 'VVIP') {
    $action = "seats.php";
}
```

in here if you read this line `echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">'` you give name for `select`  `Ticket_Type` and than in the `if statement` You use the variable `$TicketType`,  I am assuming you are checking the value for $TicketType, This problem you can solve it by changing the variable name `$TicketType` to `$Ticket_Type` In the if statement.

***you have to correct this as well at the same place***

*So even after apply the above fix, your code wont work, cause you have second problem in this code*

Now comes to the second problem, which  you made in your `if statement` , in your `if statement` in here you checking `$TicketType` value, but you don’t have value for variable `$TicketType` because when you use the `form` php don’t set the variable it set the `index` so first you have to set the value for `$TicketType` than only you can use the `if statement,`

After applying both fixes your code should look like this

**Note – (I am changing the name for `select` to TicketType )**

```
echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">'; 
    foreach ($TicketType  as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';

$Ticket_Type = $_POST['Ticket_Type']; // Now you set the value for variable 
// as your value is set, now you can type your if statement below.

if($Ticket_Type == 'VIP'){
    $action = "index.php";
}else if ($Ticket_Type == 'VVIP') {
    $action = "seats.php";
}
```

**3. Select option, pass value only from the value tag**

Third mistake you make and this one you will not notice with this code, but if you don’t learn, you will likely to make that mistake in the future, so correct this mistake as well,

***Just pay attention to this code***

```
$TicketType = array('VIP' =>'VIP', 'VVIP' =>'VVIP', 'Upper Box A'=>'Upper Box A', 'Upper Box B'=>'Upper Box B', 'Lower Box A'=>'Lower Box A', 'Lower Box B'=>'Lower Box B', 'General Admission'=>'General Admission') ;

    echo ' <select name="Ticket_Type">';
    foreach ($TicketType  as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

In here you have array, and than you are creating `select` `option` from your array which is fine, but you are making one fundamental mistakes in here, form will only passes the value form the `value` tag
so come to this line in your code

`echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";`

now change variable to `$key` to variable `$value` as well, because when you click on the submit button, again form only passes the value from value.

`echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";` to `echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";`

it wont change the out come, for this code, as in your array key and values are same, but you should know what value you are passing for the future.

*To Understand what I am trying to say here, run these two code from below, you will understand what  I am trying to say.*

***form.php***

```
<form action="seat.php" method="post">
    <select name="Ticket_Type">
<option value="key1">First</option>
        <option value="key2">Second</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Hot Air">
</form>
```

***seat.php***

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['Ticket_Type'];
echo $value;
```

run this file in the browser and than select the option, and click on the `submit button`, it will display you `key1 or key2` depending on the option you choose, not the `first or second`, as form only submit the value from value tag 
now change value tag value to One and two, and run your code again,

```
<form action="seat.php" method="post">
    <select name="Ticket_Type">;

        <option value="One">First</option>
        <option value="Two">Second</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Hot Air">
</form>
```

*Now again run the file in the browser, and chose the option and click on the submit, and see the outcome, and try to understand what is happening.*

**4 Your logic is at the wrong place**

see this code

```
if($Ticket_Type == 'VIP'){
    $action = "index.php";
}else if ($Ticket_Type == 'VVIP') {
    $action = "seats.php";
}
```

What your are trying to do here, in your head it make sense, that you will run the different different file, 
according the ticket type, but in reality it does not make any sense, because when you click on the `submit button`, than only `form` will pass the value, to the `action file`,

this one is hard to explain

ok listen you have this variable `$TicketType` in this code, it only get set after you click on the submit button, and the `action file` it never going get set in this files, so you can not have these lines in this file. (and that's why it was showing to access forbidden after adding the echo)

***Ok let's say you move this line to the different file, but still what you are trying to do with these lines is still silly, just don’t use these silly lines, and don’t try to run different different file, run single file, means give single `action`, and lets say action in the form is `book.php`***

so our  file name is `book.php`,

so starting shell for your `book.php` should look like this

```
if(!empty($_POST['Ticket_Type'])){

    // what you are basically saying that if TicketType is not empty run this code, 
// if it is empty run the else statement so the user will know that he did not select any ticket, 
//now we are going to add some more code In here

}else 'Hey you did not select any ticket';
```

**After adding the code in the middle our code will look like this**

```
if(!empty($_POST['Ticket_Type'])){

    $Ticket_Type = $_POST['Ticket_Type']; // set the value

    if($Ticket_Type == 'VIP'){ // 
//    Copy and paste the index.php file code here
}else if ($Ticket_Type == 'VVIP') {
    //copy and paste the seat.php file code here
    echo $action;
}// if you have another Ticket_Type just add another else if here, 
//Note: you can add as many else if you like, 

}else 'Hey you did not select any ticket';
```

**so just run single file action**

i am still alive, after typing all this, if you have any confusion let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your Proble is here:

```
$TicketType = array('VIP' =>'VIP', 'VVIP' =>'VVIP', 'Upper Box A'=>'Upper Box A', 'Upper Box B'=>'Upper Box B', 'Lower Box A'=>'Lower Box A', 'Lower Box B'=>'Lower Box B', 'General Admission'=>'General Admission') ;
```

And your condition for if statment is

```
if($TicketType == 'VIP'){
    $action = "index.php";
}else if ($TicketType == 'VVIP') {
    $action = "seats.php";
}
```

$TicketType is an array and you can't check it with a string, so your $action variable is not setting. and you have to provide index to check.

Comment: I also used your fist suggestion and it says access forbidden?

Comment: I think $action variable is not set because $TicketType is an array and your condition checking is string "VIP". My suggestion is to put index in $TicketType

Comment: Vidya what you are saying is not correct, but i dont blame you as i did get confused here my self, it is not array, it should $Ticket_Type value which is coming from selected option

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my error read "Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referr..."

Going off of aria_suhail_123's answer, you simply need to remove any php code surrounding your $action variable in your html like so:

```
<?php 
    if($tickettype == 'VIP'){
        $action = "seats.php"; 
    }else if($tickettype == 'VVIP'){
        $action ="seats1.php";
    }
?>

<form action= $action method="post">
```

The reason why is explained by aria_suhail_123, but since his/her response is very long... maybe this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['tickettype'])){
  
  if($tickettype == "VIP"){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "./seats.php";
</script>      
<?php  
}else if ($tickettype == "VVIP") {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "./seats1.php";
</script>      
<?php
        
}   
}else 'Hey you did not select any ticket';

?>
```